# Diode and MOSFET SMT replacement

Tags: arduino, mosfet, motor, diodes, mosfet-driver

I am working on an Arduino project where am controlling a motor through one of the Arduino I/O pins. The [motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P18SQSR) has nothing special just a regular 3-5V motor. 
In my circuit am using a diode and a N-Channel MOSFET that has low Rds, The diode is [1N4001](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1N4001-D-110363.pdf) and MOSFET is [RFP30N06LE](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/rfp30n06le-1195941.pdf). 
Everything works! so far so good.

Now am making a PCB of my circuit and i don't want to use these THT components i would like to use SMT components/alternatives.
To replace the 1N4001 diode i found [S1-A](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/S1M-D.pdf) and to replace the MOSFET i found 
[PMV15UNEAR](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMV15UNEA.pdf).

My question is simply, are the replacement components similar enough to control my 3-5V motor like how i had it working on the breadboard setup? if not do you know of any better choices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several good choices. As of now I think the selection you have done fair enough and should work.

1. The new chosen diode had maximum Reverse voltage of 50 V Rating and it should be okay for a DC motor. If you have a chance, you can choose a diode with higher reverse Vorlage Rating.
2. The \$V_{GS}\$ of chosen new MOSFET is even better than the previous one. It looks good as well, including the breakdown voltages. The current ratings I believe should be fine too.

Comment: thank you soo much really!!! i have been staring at this forum since my previous question for the past 36 hours hoping someone answers me with an informative answer such as yours! 
Thats good to hear i was worried these components might be bad choices! again thank you really. I will give it till tonight to see what others think as well :)